# Counter for Quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, performance, sorting, quicksort

My professor asked us to choose the best sorting algorithm, we chose Quicksort. The task given to us was to create a program that sorts an array of integers using the chosen algorithm but only using 1 method and to create a counter that counts how many times a line of code runs in the program to determine the fastest and best memory wise algorithm.

I know that Quicksort is great for large sets of data which gives the reason why my counter count is high but I just wanted to check if the lines where I put the counter are correct. Any suggestions?

```
public class JavaProgram {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Func {
        void call(int[] arr, int i, int j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter=0; counter++;
        System.out.println("Enter size of array: "); counter++;
        int x = sc.nextInt(); counter++;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers in array: "); counter++;
        int[] numbers = new int[x]; counter++;
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = sc.nextInt(); counter++;
        }

        Func swap = (int[] arr, int i, int j) -> {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }; counter++;

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); counter++;
        stack.push(0); counter++;
        stack.push(numbers.length); counter++;

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) { counter++;
            int end = stack.pop(); counter++;
            int start = stack.pop(); counter++;
            if (end - start < 2) { counter++;
                continue;
            } counter++;

            // partitioning part
            int position = start + ((end - start) / 2); counter++;
            int low = start; counter++;
            int high = end - 2; counter++;
            int piv = numbers[position]; counter++;
            swap.call(numbers, position, end - 1); counter++;
            while (low < high) { counter++;
                if (numbers[low] < piv) { counter++;
                    low++; counter++;
                } else if (numbers[high] >= piv) { counter++;
                    high--; counter++;
                } else { counter++;
                    swap.call(numbers, low, high); counter++;
                }
            }
            position = high; counter++;
            if (numbers[high] < piv) { counter++;
                position++; counter++;
            }
            swap.call(numbers, end - 1, position); counter++;


            stack.push(position + 1); counter++;
            stack.push(end); counter++;
            stack.push(start); counter++;
            stack.push(position); counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(numbers)); counter++;
        System.out.println("Counter: "+counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you aiming to count? It looks like you've sprinkled `counter++` after every line without much thought as to what exactly you're counting. You need a well-defined target to measure, otherwise how do you know if you're doing it right or not? Typically when analyzing sort algorithm performance people will measure the number of comparisons or the number of swaps.

Comment: Are you sure that they are that strict on the number of method the program may have? Would it be fine to have two: the main() (including the int array parsing/input) and the another that implements the algorithm that could be recursive (call itself). Or was you instructor explicit about avoiding recursion?

Comment: how on earth line count is related to memory efficiency or performance?

Comment: He just said to add counter++; after every line of code.